# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to write a service using Spring 5, however I receive a Dependency Injection issue. I'm having problems using @Resource.I have recently migrated from Spring 4 to Spring 5.0.5 and have the following jars in the classapath

- spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE
- spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE
- spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE
- spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE
- spring-expression-5.0.5.RELEASE
- spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE
- junit-4.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are defining your context configuration for your class as TestClass.OptionalConfiguration then this is the only configuration your tests know about. If you want to define CiScheduledExecutor as a bean in this context as well then you need to component scan for it in your test configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.base.package")
static class OptionalConfiguration {
        @Bean
        List<Item> someString() {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        @Bean
        Object foo(List<Item> obj) {
            return new Object();
        }
    }
```

Although if you are doing integration like tests that require pulling in several bean definitions from your actual runtime Spring context then you should consider using @SpringBootTest which does a lot of the work for you, see here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: Is there a way to look for the beans present in the entire webapp instead of adding @ComponentScan("my.base.package") in each of the classes. I would like to add a configuration in a xml file that will resolve all the beans present in a web app. In Spring i had a custom code written to look for beans in a webapp.

Comment: Yes, if you are using Spring boot then you can use @SpringBootTest and point it to your main method and then it will load all the beans defined in your webapp for your tests. See the link in my answer

Comment: No, i am not using Spring Boot. I am running the above code in a Jetty container. The junit test runs fine but when i deploy the code inside the container i am getting BeanCreationException. I had created the junit just to isolate the issue and find the root cause. The rest of code is running in Jetty where i am facing the issue.